# Prove Weierstrass Theorem using Fejer Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, weierstrass-approximation, fejer-kernel

Using the following theorem: The trigonometric polynomials ($\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$) are uniformly dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$ (functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ that are continuous and periodic with a period of $2\pi$.

> Prove: For every continuous function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ there exists a series of polynomials $\{P_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\}$, such that: $P_n \to f$ uniformly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It suffices you show the Taylor series of the sine and cosine converge uniformly on compact intervals.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Why is that true?

Comment: you will have shown that there exists a series of polynomial that converge to a trigonometric polynomial, and since they're dense in periodic functions of period $2\pi$ and $f$ is in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ you can conclude

Comment: The Cesaro sums of the sequence of partial sums of the Fourier series are just averages of trigonometric polynomials, and therefore themselves trigonometric polynomials. [Fejer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) tells you that they converge uniformly to the function.

Comment: @UmShmum Check the formula for the remainder.

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand why it suffice. Trigonometric polynomial are $\mathbb{C} \to \mathb{R)$ not from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathb{R)$